Using Dominated Convergence Theorem to show limit of Riemann integral of a function is 0
Consider the sequence
$$f_k(x) = \frac{(1-x)^k\cos(k/x)}{\sqrt{x}}$$
I want to show that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_k(x)dx=0 $$
My main idea behind my approach is to use the fact that on finite intervals, Riemann integrable functions are Lebesgue integrable, and then to show that the function satisfies the hypothesis of the Dominated Convergence Theorem to get the desired result. This is as follows; I would like clarification on whether or not this proof is okay, or if it is missing details (which I presume it probably is)
Proof: First, we note that on $[0,1]$,
$$|f_k(x)|= \frac{|(1-x)^k\cos(k/x)|}{\sqrt{x}}\leq \frac{(1-x)^k}{\sqrt{x}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
There is an explosion at $x=0$, but we note that the inequality is otherwise fine from this point. Let $\mu$ denote Lebesgue's measure. $\mu\{0\}=0$ and since this property holds on $(0,1]$, $1/\sqrt{x}$ dominates $|f_k(x)|$ for almost every $x$, and for every $k$. Also, we note that for almost every $x\in[0,1]$ (i.e., excluding 0 as before), the sequence converges pointwise to 0. Since the sequence is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$, it is Lebesgue measurable there and we can use the Lebesgue integral to evaluate the Riemann integral. By the Dominated Convergence Theorem then,
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{[0,1]}\frac{(1-x)^k\cos(x/k)}{\sqrt{x}}d\mu(x) = \int_{[0,1]}\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{(1-x)^k\cos(x/k)}{\sqrt{x}}d\mu(x) = \int_{[0,1]}0d\mu(x)=0$$
The reason I think this may not be a complete proof is that I recall my professor saying we may need to use some squeezing approach to show this. Any feedback is appreciated.
